# django cmdline(manage.py shell) get DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, shell

As we know, in django framework, i run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and then, create an object(model) from the web, i can get this object through web

but, when i try to get it through django shell started before, i got DoesNotExist exception

```
DoesNotExist: QueueData matching query does not exist.
```

the only way cat get this new object is exit old django shell, and start one

the question is: **how cat i get new object created by web from the django shell started before, without rerun the django shell?**

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, is very strange, because using `shell` and `models` you get objects from database (perform query) when you need them

Comment: I think you are working with stale data in your shell. You probably create something on your web view, and then try to access a stale object in your shell instead of querying and getting a fresh one,

Comment: Hm, i think i got the reason: i was raised by the MySQL REPEATABLE READ. http://www.no-ack.org/2010/07/mysql-transactions-and-django.html Thanks all :-)

Answer (score 0):

actually they both read your database so even you create an object instance from web you need to be able to access this object from your django shell

just query your object to see all your created objects

Yourmodel.objects.all()